# What is the json file I need to read?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, python-requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcTKb.png)I need to download satellite images using python. I have found a code in GitHub but I did not understand what at this line. Please help me what it exactly is.
Visit https://github.com/kscottz/PythonFromSpace/blob/master/TheBasics.ipynb

```
import sys
import os
import json
import scipy
import urllib
import datetime 
import urllib3
import rasterio
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from osgeo import gdal
from planet import api
from planet.api import filters
from traitlets import link
import rasterio.tools.mask as rio_mask
from shapely.geometry import mapping, shape
from IPython.display import display, Image, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from ipyleaflet import (
    Map,
    Marker,
    TileLayer, ImageOverlay,
    Polyline, Polygon, Rectangle, Circle, CircleMarker,
    GeoJSON,
    DrawControl
)

%matplotlib inline
# will pick up api_key via environment variable PL_API_KEY
# but can be specified using `api_key` named argument
api_keys = json.load(open("apikeys.json",'r'))
client = api.ClientV1(api_key=api_keys["PLANET_API_KEY"])
# Make a slippy map to get GeoJSON
```

> ```
> api_keys = json.load(open("apikeys.json",'r')) 
> client = api.ClientV1(api_key=api_keys["PLANET_API_KEY"])
> ```

What is the meaning of these two lines. What file should I upload for apikeys.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow this link to get an API Key.
https://support.planet.com/hc/en-us/articles/212318178-What-is-my-API-key-

apikeys.json is a JSON file of following format/content in json:

```
{"PLANET_API_KEY":"<Some API Key here>"}
```

json.load(...) API loads this json file as a dictionary

Comment: I have my api key but when I put the api Key it saysno such fire or directory is found for the line api_keys = json.load(open("apikeys.json",'r'))

Comment: Please give the complete path from root in the file name. For e.g., if /Users/abc/Downloads/apikeys.json is the full path, then, api_keys = json.load(open("/Users/abc/Downloads/apikeys.json",'r'))

Comment: But which file should I upload. I dont have any file as such.

Comment: If your API keys is "abcdxyz" then you create a apikeys.json file with following content: {"PLANET_API_KEY":"abcdxyz"}

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped me

Comment: Nikhil, please accept the answer so that others can find it.

Comment: This is my first time here so I did not know about it. I have accepted it. Thanks a lot